# What's the contribution of different types of river sources?

Tags: hydrology, rivers

There are different types of [river sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_source), most people might think of **springs**, **melting snow** or **glaciers**, but other types of sources can include [**wet meadows**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Poudre_Pass) or **marshland**.

In terms of volume, what is the contribution of each type of source?

Comment: Contribution to what?

Comment: @BHF of water, volume. e.g. X% of the Amazon's water is sourced from springs/snow/etc.

Comment: It is still unclear to me what you mean.

Comment: @BHF What part in particular are you unsure about? Maybe you can be more specific so I can address them, instead of trying to rephrase the same question. All rivers have a number of different sources, and these sources could be different types. A river might not get all its water from springs, for example. Some could come from melted snow. What I want to know is, out of the total volume of water in the river, what proportion comes from each type.

Comment: Do you mean the volume of the rivers? Do you mean the flux at the mouth? The amount of water swelling at the spring? Or something else?

Comment: @BHF any is fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17253/discussion-between-bhf-and-congusbongus).

Comment: It depends of the basin, in mountain zones perhaps the rain is the main contribution. But near the poles maybe the melting snow.

Comment: From the question and the comments - OP seem to assume that any and all river have the same input ratio from various sources. IMO this is badly formulated and / or is impossible to answer. Let's take the St Lawrence taking source in the Great Lakes - water input ratio can be estimated. Then this would be the same ratio than the Nile ? Or any randon proglacial river flowing out from Greenland? There is no answer possible for all rivers - a specific river should be named - this question should be closed

Comment: @fre0n maybe OP is talking about global volumetric averages?

Comment: @Isopycnal Oscillation possibly global yes it is a possibility I agree. But since far from all stream are characterized for their respective contributions,  a global average would be a rough estimate at best. And streams can be so different fron one another that I hardly see how making this figure would be any useful (imo). Still would be curious if some estimates exist